# Equation for the line of intersection between two planes

Tags: equation-solving, intersection

I have two equations:

```
{2 x + y + z == 1, 3 x - 2 y - z == 5}
```

And I have calculated the answers on paper, which gave me $x = 1 + t$, $y = -1 + 5t$ and $z = -7t$.

So my actual problem is how I should do this with *Mathematica*. I haven't really worked with *Mathematica* that much, and therefore I don't know how I should get these answers, and also plot the intersection of these two planes.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me or show me some way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Just to illustrate some other things. You can which parametrization you like. In this case parametrization in terms of x:

```
sol = {x, y, z} /. First@Solve[eq, {y, z}];
Show[Plot3D[{1 - 2 x - y, 3 x - 2 y - 5}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, LightYellow}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[sol, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Column[{SwatchLegend[{LightBlue, LightYellow}, eq], 
     LineLegend[{Red}, {"Parametrization: " <> ToString@sol}]}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You could use

```
sol = Solve[{2 x + y + z == 1, 3 x - 2 y - z == 5}, {x, y}] // Simplify
```

giving

```
Out[1] {{x->1-z/7,y->-((5 z)/7)-1}}
```

This gives x, y in terms of z.  To parameterize in terms of t do

```
sol /. z -> -7 t
```

giving

```
Out[2] {{x->t+1,y->5 t-1}}
```

and of course `z->-7 t`

Answer (score 5):

This may be overkill, but I think it is interesting to use `RegionIntersection` here.

```
plane1 = 
 InfinitePlane[{x, y, z} /. 
   FindInstance[
    2 x + y + z == 1 && {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[], {x, y, z}, 
    Reals, 3]]
plane2 = InfinitePlane[{x, y, z} /. 
   FindInstance[
    3 x - 2 y - z == 5 && {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[], {x, y, z}, 
    Reals, 3]]
line = RegionIntersection[
  plane1, plane2
  ]
Graphics3D[{Red, plane1, plane2, Blue, line}]

(* InfinitePlane[{{31/302, 1, -(31/151)}, {1, 1, -2}, {33/302, 0, 118/151}}] *)
(* InfinitePlane[{{31/302, 1, -(2021/302)}, {1, 1, -4}, {33/302, 0, -(1411/302)}}] *)
(* InfiniteLine[{7/5, 1, -(14/5)}, {-(1/5), -1, 7/5}] *)
```

[image]

Now you have your line as an `InfiniteLine` object, you can convert this to a parametric form via the formulas [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html).

```
{point, vector} = List @@ line;
equation = point + vector t
(* {7/5 - t/5, 1 - t, -(14/5) + (7 t)/5} *)
```

Which I can show graphically is equivalent to the form OP seeks,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
  equation,
  {1 + t, 5 t - 1, -7 t}
  }, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two planes always intersect in a line as long as they are not parallel. See also [Plane-Plane Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane-PlaneIntersection.html).

You can plot two planes with [ContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html),

```
h = (2 x + y + z) - 1

g = (3 x - 2 y - z) - 5

ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

And the Intersection as a *Mesh Function*,

```
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}
, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}
, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}
, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}
, ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange
, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

[image]

See [MeshFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'll just leave the following simple code for computing the direction numbers of a line given its two generating planes:

```
eqs = {2 x + y + z == 1, 3 x - 2 y - z == 5};
coefs = Normal[Last[CoefficientArrays[eqs, {x, y, z}]]];
dn = RotateLeft[Det /@ First[Partition[coefs, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, 1]]]
   {1, 5, -7}
```

Then, just generate some point on the line; e.g.

```
p0 = {x, y, z} /. First[FindInstance[eqs, {z, y, x}]]
   {1, -1, 0}
```

and one can now either use the parametric equations `p0 + t dn` for computations or plotting, or use `InfiniteLine[p0, dn]` for visualization.

Answer (score 1):

The two-points-determine-a-line method:

```
eqs = {2 x + y + z == 1, 3 x - 2 y - z == 5};
Replace[
  {x, y, z} /. FindInstance[eqs, {x, y, z}, Reals, 2],
  {p_, q_} :> p + t (q - p)]
```

> ```
> (*  {1/2 + t/10, -(7/2) + t/2, 7/2 - (7 t)/10}  *)
> ```

With rational equations, we can look for integral solutions:

```
param = Replace[
   {x, y, z} /. FindInstance[eqs, {x, y, z}, Integers, 2],
   {p_, q_} :> p + t (q - p)]
```

> ```
> (*  {5 + t, 19 + 5 t, -28 - 7 t}  *)
> ```

We can find an integral point closest to the origin for slightly simpler parametric coordinates:

```
param /. t -> 
   t + ArgMin[#.# &@{5 + t, 19 + 5 t, -28 - 7 t}, t, 
     Integers] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  {1 + t, -1 + 5 t, -7 t}  *)
> ```