# How to obtain the coordinates of the intersection line of two surfaces?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, computational-geometry

I can plot the intersection line of two surfaces $f$, $g$ by using:

```
ContourPlot3D[
  f[x, y, z] == 0, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, f[x, y, z] - g[x, y, z]]}
]
```

But I need to do some calculations based on the intersection line. Or I need 100 (for example) group data of $(x, y, z)$ on the line. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you seen [Equation for the line of intersection between two planes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112416/equation-for-the-line-of-intersection-between-two-planes/112427#112427)

Comment: yes, but the equation of f,g is complicated, there is no simple line equation of the intersection line.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what kinds of calculations you'll want to do on the intersection line;  but to get a sample of points on the intersection line, you could use `DiscretizeRegion` and `MeshCoordinates`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 1;
g[x_, y_, z_] = x - 2 y + z - 2;
ContourPlot3D[{f[x, y, z] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[{f[x, y, z] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y, z}]]
```

[image]

```
MeshCoordinates[reg]

(* {{0.327426, -0.339412, 0.99375}, {0.327446, -0.339402, 0.99375}, ... } *)
```

In this example, I get 176 points along the intersection curve using the default settings for each function.  If your initial results contain too few (or too many) points, you could try tweaking the `MaxCellMeasure` option when you use the `DiscretizeRegion` function.

Comment: Thank you, But I still have problems and I posted it as answer below.

Comment: The new question is here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114051/projection-of-a-3d-curve-to-2d

Answer (score 5):

For version 9:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y^2 - z^2
g[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1
cp3d = ContourPlot3D[{f[x, y, z]==0, g[x, y, z]==0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Thick, Red}}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.7], Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 400];
points =  Cases[Normal@cp3d, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]];
Length@points
```

> 121

```
lpp3d = ListPointPlot3D[points, PlotStyle->PointSize[Large]]/. Point -> (Sphere[#, .05] &);

Row[{cp3d /. Line -> Tube, Show[cp3d, lpp3d]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, using `MeshFunctions`

```
cp3d2 = ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 400, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[.7], MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z] - g[x, y, z]]}];
points2 = Cases[Normal@cp3d2, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]];
Length@points2
```

> 201

```
lpp3d2 = ListPointPlot3D[points2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]] /. 
   Point -> (Sphere[#, .05] &);

Row[{cp3d2 /. Line -> Tube, Show[cp3d2, lpp3d2]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here are two additional approaches, one uses `RegionIntersection`, the other uses `DiscretizeGraphics`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 1;
g[x_, y_, z_] = x - 2 y + z - 2;

regF = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, y, z}];
regG = ImplicitRegion[g[x, y, z] == 0, {x, y, z}];

reg = DiscretizeRegion @ RegionIntersection[regF, regG]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MeshCoordinates @ reg // Length
```

> 235

**Method 2**

```
gr = ContourPlot3D[{f[x, y, z] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
     ContourStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]], 
     BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Red}, 
     Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40];

reg = DiscretizeGraphics[gr, Line];
MeshCoordinates @ reg // Length
```

> 107