# Projection of a 3d curve to 2d

Tags: geometry, projection

This question is related to:

[How to obtain the coordinates of the intersection line of two surfaces?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113956/how-to-obtain-the-coordinates-of-the-intersection-line-of-two-surfaces)

Read the link first.

First, I have tried `MaxCellMeasure->0.5`, `MaxCellMeasure->{"Length"->0.5}` and `MaxCellMeasure->{"Area"->0.5}`, and change the number 0.5. It seems that the numbers of point doesn't change.

Secondly, it's very fast to run your code, but it takes about minutes to run my code with my `f[x,y,z]`, `g[x,y,z]`. And this is my code:

```
Clear[f,g];
f[x_,y_,z_,t_]:=x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2-t^2/4;
g[x_,y_,z_]:=Piecewise[{{(x-1/2)^2+y^2+z^2-1/16,(x-1/2)^2+y^2-1/16<=0&&z>=0}},z];
reg=DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[{f[x,y,z,2]==0, g[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y, z}]];
MeshCoordinates[reg]
```

Is it because I used Piecewise in g function that it needs more time to run the code?

Third, what I want to do next is below. In fact, I want to plot the projection of the intersection line on xy plane. And this is point projection, as shown below

[image]

Connect (0,0,1) and one point on the intersection line, extend it to intersect with xy plane. The yellow pint is want I am looking for. Repeat this for all points on the intersection line, then I can get a closed curve on xy plane. And I need to plot the curve in a 2-dimensional figure, instead of three-dimensional figure here.(I don't want to use Plot3D+Viewpoint to show a 2d curve in 3d coordinate, because the exported pdf file will be large.) I can calculate the yellow points' coordinate (x',y') based on (x,y,z) of red points on the intersection line. x'=x/(1-z),y'=y(1-z). But how to achieve this?

Or maybe I should use another way: use ParametricPlot

```
ParametricPlot[{x/(1-z),y/(1-z)},{x,y,z}] and x,y,z satisfy f[x,y,z]==g[x,y,z]
```

Comment: "Read the link first" - Not the best approach to asking well-received questions. Please make your question self-contained, and perhaps shorted as well. Note also that you are linking to a deleted question; not everybody will have access to those. Finally, please format your code (see e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)).

Answer (score 9):

It actually takes me a fraction of a second to run your code (version 10.4 on OS X 10.11.4).

You can use `MaxCellMeasure` to get more points:

```
Length@MeshCoordinates@
     DiscretizeRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[{f[x, y, z, 2] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y, 
        z}], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}] & /@ {0.1, 0.05, 0.005} // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.368696, {76, 101, 965}} *)
```

One way to achieve the projection is to use `ScalingTransform`:

```
curve = MeshCoordinates[reg];
center = {0, 0, 1};
proj = ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1}/(1 - #[[3]]), center][#] & /@ curve;
Graphics3D[{Point@curve, Blue,Point@proj, Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image]

If you want to plot the points in 2D, you can sort the list by the closest neighbor and then plot

```
ls = proj;
pt = proj[[1]];

line = Prepend[Table[
    ls = DeleteCases[ls, pt];
    pt = First@Nearest[ls, pt],
    {n, 1, Length@ls - 1}
    ], pt];

Graphics[Line@line[[All, 1 ;; 2]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Good, thank you. My mathematica is Version 10 on  Win8. And the data in proj is like (x,y,z) right. What if I only want to plot (x,y)?

Comment: Version 10.0 student edition on Win8. I am confused why it takes so long.

Comment: Length@MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[{f[x, y, z, 2] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y,  z}], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}] & /@ {0.1,  0.5} // AbsoluteTiming  (*{240.931,{157,157}} *)

if g=x+y+z, (*{1.4330,{115,115}}*) 

the maxcellmeasure didn't work.

Comment: Perfect. I still need to figure out why maxcellmeasure doesn't work in my computer and why it takes so long time to sun the code. Is there any hint to solve this?

Comment: I can reproduce the slowness in version 10.0 and 10.1 and I would consider it as a bug. It looks like it has been fixed started from version 10.2.

Comment: Yeah. I have tried in 10.2, and there is no this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Then I want to plot the lines in one figure with  f[x,y,z,2.0] and maxcellmeasure-> {"Length" -> 0.05}, f[x,y,z,2.1] with  "Length" -> 0.1  ... f[x,y,z,2.5] with "Length" -> 0.3. Should I repeat the code 6 times or is there any methods to simplify the code?  @xslittlegrass

Comment: @QiZhong I think you can use 'Table' to do that.