# How are the projections of this plot made?

Tags: plotting

I want to make projections of a 3D plot as shown in this image [image: Plot].

I took this image from this paper: [Multiphoton state engineering by heralded interference between single photons and coherent states](https://sci-hub.ru/10.1103/physreva.86.043820). I know how to make a 3D plot like this. I only want to know how these projections on the face grids were made. I tried making this by using the "projecttoWalls" function from this question: [How to project 3d image in the planes xy, xz, yz?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199612/86226) but it gives me a projection of my plot. Can anybody tell me how to draw projections like in the above image? (I get that these projections are like a 2D version of this plot but I don't know how to make them.)

This is the code of my 3D plot:

```
    w0 = (2*(7 - 20*I*Sqrt[2]*p - 24*p^2 - 20*Sqrt[2]*q + 48*I*p*q + 24*q^2 + 8*(-3 + 8*p^2 + 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + 8*Sqrt[2]*q - 8*q^2)*Conjugate[p]^2 + 
      4*(-5*Sqrt[2] + 16*Sqrt[2]*p^2 + 28*q - 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2 - 4*I*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q))*Conjugate[q] + 8*(3 - 8*p^2 - 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2)*Conjugate[q]^2 + 
      4*Conjugate[p]*(-16*I*Sqrt[2]*p^2 - 4*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q) + I*(5*Sqrt[2] - 28*q + 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2) - 4*(-8*I*p^2 + 8*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + I*(3 - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2))*Conjugate[q])))/
    E^(2*Abs[-(1/Sqrt[2]) + I*p + q]^2)/(3*Pi*(Sqrt[2] - 4*I*p - 4*q)*(Sqrt[2] + 4*I*Conjugate[p] - 4*Conjugate[q]));

    p1 = Plot3D[w0, {q, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All];
    p2 = DensityPlot[w0, {q, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 90];
    level = -0.4;
    gr = Graphics3D[{Texture[p2], EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{-5, -5, level}, {5, -5, level}, {5, 5, level}, {-5, 5, level}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];
    f1 = Show[p1, gr, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}];
```

Comment: Perhaps  [How to project 3d image in the planes xy, xz, yz?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199612/how-to-project-3d-image-in-the-planes-xy-xz-yz) helps

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No it does not help with this graph. I have mentioned it in the question as well. It creates projections but I want them like in the plot in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question in detail. From your image I cann't see what kind of projections you're looking for. Are these the outer contours of the 3D-plot?

Comment: I am talking about the projections or waveforms on the gridded walls. Maybe these are not projections, but rather a 2D form of the 3D plot. I am sorry if I am not being clear:)

Comment: So do I! My question: How  these projections depend on the 3D-Plot?

Comment: Actually my supervisor showed me this plot and asked me to make my 3D plots like this but I coudn't understand either how they are related to the 3D plot. I am also confused.

Comment: From what I have understood by seeing the other plots in the paper: [Multiphoton state engineering by heralded interference between single photons and coherent states](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.043820), these projections are like a 2D version of showing the changes in the 3D plots.

Comment: And you cannot ask your supervisor again to clarify?

Comment: Well he is not available this week.

Comment: The link you gave doesn't allow free access...

Comment: There is an email to contact the authors on the paper, I would email them and ask what is depicted in the projections onto the walls of figs. 3,4.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Use this: [Multiphoton state engineering by heralded interference between single photons and coherent states](https://sci-hub.ru/10.1103/physreva.86.043820).

Comment: For what it's worth they look like plots of W(x,0), W(0,p) respectively.

Comment: Looks like a slice of f(x,y) at some x say x=0.  To get the slice on the left wall  at myX=-5, I would use `ParametricPlot3D[{-5,y,f(0,y)},{y,-5,5}]`.  Can you post the f(x,y) or some other similar f(x,y)?

Comment: @josh I have edited the function in my question and now `w0`  is almost like the function used to make the 3D plot in the figure.

Comment: @Anaya:  Ok sorry.  Didn't see that.  Can't get to it now.  Will work on it later if no one else posts.

Comment: @josh Okay thank you:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redefine your expression as a function of $p$ and $q$:

```
ClearAll[w0]
w0[p_, q_] := (2*(7 - 20*I*Sqrt[2]*p - 24*p^2 - 20*Sqrt[2]*q + 
        48*I*p*q + 24*q^2 + 
        8*(-3 + 8*p^2 + 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + 8*Sqrt[2]*q - 8*q^2)*
         Conjugate[p]^2 + 
        4*(-5*Sqrt[2] + 16*Sqrt[2]*p^2 + 28*q - 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2 - 
           4*I*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q))*Conjugate[q] + 
        8*(3 - 8*p^2 - 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2)*
         Conjugate[q]^2 + 
        4*Conjugate[
          p]*(-16*I*Sqrt[2]*p^2 - 4*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q) + 
           I*(5*Sqrt[2] - 28*q + 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2) - 
           4*(-8*I*p^2 + 8*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + 
              I*(3 - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2))*Conjugate[q])))/
    E^(2*Abs[-(1/Sqrt[2]) + I*p + q]^2)/(3*
     Pi*(Sqrt[2] - 4*I*p - 4*q)*(Sqrt[2] + 4*I*Conjugate[p] - 
       4*Conjugate[q]));
```

Generate the main plot and projections using `ParametricPlot3D` (I use a modification of a technique I learned [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164668/27951)):

```
ClearAll[full3D, xzplane, yzplane]
full3D[x_, y_] := {x, y, w0[x, y]}
xzplane[x_, y_] := {5, y, w0[0, y] + 0.15}
yzplane[x_, y_] := {x, -5, w0[x, 1] + 0.15}

pplot = ParametricPlot3D[
   {full3D[x, y], xzplane[x, y], yzplane[x, y]},
   {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
   PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None,
   ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors",
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2/3}
]
```

[image: 3D plot with 2D projections]

Then generate the DensityPlot and add it as a texture, as you did in your own code:

```
density = DensityPlot[
   w0[p, q], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5},
   PlotPoints -> 150,
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> All
];

level = -0.3;
gr = Graphics3D[{
       Texture[p2], EdgeForm[], 
       Polygon[{{-5, -5, level}, {5, -5, level}, {5, 5, level}, {-5, 5, level}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
     Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[
  {pplot, gr},
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
  ViewPoint -> {-2, 2.5, 0.5}, ViewVertical -> {-0.3, 0.3, 1}
]
```

[image: 3D plot with density at the bottom]

Comment: Thank you so much! Moreover, for beginners like me working on a similar problem, using the command `Exclusions->None` inside the `ParametricPlot3D` command removes the break in the left projection. :)

Comment: Is there a way to remove the mesh and still have the parametric curves on the walls because when I use `Mesh->None`, my parametric curves disappear and only the 3D plot remains?