# Plotting the domain of a 3d surface found implicitly with ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I obtained a surface defined by $f(x,y,z) = 0$ using ContouPlot3D. How can I plot the domain of this surface in the $(x,y)$ plan? In other words I am looking for the projection of the surface onto the $(x,y)$ plan. Note that I am not trying to have the surface and its projection on the same figure like in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164663/2d-projection-of-a-3d-surface), only a 2d region of the domain. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you name your plot (Graphics3D-object )

```
plt=ContourPlot3D[x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

you can change the points to x,y (2D) and use the Graphicsstructure:

```
plot[[1]] /.GraphicsComplex[p_List, rest__] :>GraphicsComplex[Map[Most[#] &, p], rest];
Graphics[%]
```

[image]

or change the viewpoint of your 3D-Plot

```
Show[plot, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
```

Comment: "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted."
Still, I can't help writing to say thank you!

Comment: Now, could you please help me doing the same thing, i.e finding the 2d domain of a surface lying in a 3d space, but when my surface in not defined by $f(x,y,z)=0$ anymore, but rather as the intersection of a volume obtained using RegionPlot3D, called vol, with a surface obtained via ContourPlot3D, let's call it surf?