# Projecting the stationary points of a function below its 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, projection

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
f[r_] := 
 1 + r^2/(
   2 α) (1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 α ((2 M)/r^3 - q^2/r^4 - 1/l^2)])

M = rh/2 + q^2/(2 rh) + rh^3/(2 l^2) + α/(2 rh);

T[rh_] := (rh^2 - q^2 - α + 3 rh^4 l^-2)/(
 4 π rh (rh^2 + 2 α))

V[r_] := f[r] (En^2/f[r] + L^2/r^2 + 1)

q = 0.02; α = 0.0065; l = 1; En = 0; L = 20;

rhmin = SolveValues[T[rh] == 0, rh, Reals][[2]]

Plot3D[V[r], {rh, rhmin, 1}, {r, rh, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

which gives me the following 3DPlot:

[image: 3dplot]

Now I find the stationary points of $V(r)$, which include both the local maxima and minima:

```
rsolmax[rh_] = SolveValues[{V'[r] == 0, V''[r] < 0}, r][[{3, 4, 5}]];

rsolmin[rh_] = SolveValues[{V'[r] == 0, V''[r] > 0}, r][[{6, 7}]];
```

and get this 2D plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{rsolmax[rh], rsolmin[rh]}], {rh, rhmin, 0.8776235}]
```

[image: 2dplot]

Now I wish to project this plot of stationary points just below the 3DPlot, which should look something like [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.11912.pdf):

[image: paper]

How to get the desired result? Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ContourPlot` or `ContourPlot3D` to draw `V'[r]==0` and set the range of `z` to `{z, -800, -1000}`.

We use `V''[r]` as the mesh shading functions  and set `Mesh->{{0}}` to determinate where `V''[r]>0` and `V''[r]<0`.

```
Clear[plot, belt]; plot = 
 Plot3D[V[r], {rh, rhmin, 1}, {r, rh, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{rh, r, z}, Blend[{LightBlue, Blue}, z]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AxesLabel -> {rh, r, V}];
belt = ContourPlot3D[
   V'[r] == 0, {rh, rhmin, 1}, {r, rh, 5}, {z, -800, -1000}, 
   PlotRange -> All, MeshFunctions -> Function[{rh, r, z}, V''[r]], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Green, Pink}];
Show[plot, belt, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {0.95, -3.16, 0.56}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a clever answer. I get similar results when I increase `PlotPoints` in the Contour Plot. Just one doubt, how can I choose my colour function to distinguish between the local maxima and the minima?

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this is a starting point (assuming the OP code):

```
f[x_, y_] := V'[y] /. rh -> x
p = Plot3D[V[r], {rh, rhmin, 1}, {r, rh, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MeshFunctions -> (f[#1, #2] &), Mesh -> {{0}}]
```

Projection:

```
pts = p[[1, 1, 1]];
i = Cases[p, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[2]];
crit = {#1, #2, -10000} & @@@ pts[[i]];
Show[p, Graphics3D[Line[crit]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You may achieve a projection using Texture. A nice example can be found in: [2D projection of a 3D surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164663/2d-projection-of-a-3d-surface)

```
tex = Plot[
   Evaluate[{rsolmax[rh], rsolmin[rh]}], {rh, rhmin, 0.8776235}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], Axes -> False];
Graphics3D[{First[pl], Texture[tex], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, -1000}, {1, 0, -1000}, {1, 5, -1000}, {0, 
     5, -1000}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True]
```

[image]