# Bessel Beam , how it is possible to plot a 3D with a 2D projection in one plot?

Tags: plotting

Sincerely, I am new in Mathematica,  I  checked all the previous post.

The idea is to plot a 3D Bessel function  with a 2D projection

They can be generated as follows.

```
Plot3D[BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

DensityPlot[BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]
The final goal is to obtain a similar  picture as was included

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to join both plots 3D and 2D  in an single one

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164663/3066) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114051/3066)

Comment: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/placing-a-contourplot-under-a-plot3d/) might help you too.

Comment: See https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1396065?p_p_auth=Zn5cux5T

Answer (score 8):

```
p1 = Plot3D[BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];

p2 = DensityPlot[
   BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> 300, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Frame -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];

p3 = Plot3D[-1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Texture[p2], 
   Mesh -> None];

Show[p1, p3, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Okkes, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Let's call the second plot

```
pic = DensityPlot[BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

pic is a Graphicsobject `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[arg]]`, arg[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfZB.jpg)] is a twodimensional list of points. The third dimension of arg[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfZB.jpg)], for example `z==-1`, has to be added.

```
arg = Apply[List, pic[[1]]];
```

We now have to change the pointlist 2D->3D

```
pic3D=Graphics3D[Apply[GraphicsComplex, {Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], -1} &, arg[[1]]],arg[[2]], arg[[3]]}]]
```

This 3D-picture can be displayed together with the first

```
Show[{Plot3D[BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], pic3D}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrich, thank you very much!